# Blue icons lose quality in tree view

Tags: .net, treeview, icons, imagelist

Here are some pictures of what I'm dealing with:

[image]

If you look closely, the items in the `TreeView` (in the background behind the "Add Item" window) have low quality icons.  The same `ImageList` is used for the `ListView` inside of of the "Add Item" dialog, however.

Not sure if you can tell, but the icon for the "World" node (above both of the "PrimitiveCuboid" nodes) displays at its original quality.  Basically all of the icons do except for this icon (and one other similar looking icon).

What kinds of things can cause this and how can I fix it?  He low-rez icons seem very miss placed in my application.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer or not without seeing more of your code, but you might want to check the `ColorDepth` property of the `ImageList` to ensure that it is `Depth24Bit` or `Depth32Bit`.  It if works, let me know and I'll post this as the answer.

Comment: @Dan :: Sorry, but it's set for 32bit.

Comment: if are you adding .ico files. Check to make sure that you only have the parts(16x16 32bit eg) in the icon representing the colordepth and size you need. I think i've seen this if your icon has many different depths/sizes(16x16 8bit, 16x16 32bit, 32x32 8bit, etc) , the tree selected the wrong one.

Comment: @PaulFarry :: Well, they're all `.png` files.  Not sure why that would be a problem.